# Completely stumped by "is not recognized by the 'identify' command" error in rails/paperclip on windows dev box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, paperclip

Nothing I have tried seems to have any impact at all on this error.  The code is working on both a Mac Pro dev maching as well as our Ubunto 9.10 server.  Dev work is using Mongrel not Passenger.

I am fully and completely stumped.  Willing to try anything.

I followed this: http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/11/2/goodbye-attachment_fu-hello-paperclip
to the letter.

I tried installing both 32 and 64 bit versions (on XP 64).

Updated config with:

> require "paperclip"
>   Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\ImageMagick\ImageMagick-6.6.3-Q16'
>   Paperclip.options[:swallow_stderr] = false

System is: 
XP 64 bit service pack 2
Rails 2.3.8
paperclip 2.3.3
aws-s3 0.6.2

Answer (score 1):

There is some goofy stuff going on in the paperclip.rb file. It adds single quotes around command line arguments. If I can recall, I believe its on line 133 and the line looks like this:

... '#{m}' ...

Just remove the single quotes.

If that doesn't help there was also an issue with there being spaces in the ImageMagick path. It didn't like C:\Program Files..., so I had to change it to C:\Progra~1...

That seemed to do the trick for me. That will at least get the identify executable running. I am currently having issues with running convert and am completely confused. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the last couple of releases of paperclip when running on Windows.
I rollback to a version where it worked but there is a fix that someone has since mentioned. See my comment here + the other fix below:

http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/issue/220/#comment_333169

Answer (score 0):

One thing I just found out as well on windows this command "150x150>" makes problems if you go for Brandon's version as '>' is used for piping on windows boxes. Maybe use something like "150x150#" instead.