# why doesn't 'which identify' work for ImageMagick on Windows machine?

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm trying to get paperclip and ImageMagick to work on a Windows 7 machine using Ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.7. ImageMagick appears to have installed fine, since I did the `imdisplay` command that the ImageMagick installer told me to do, and it worked. A basic paperclip attachment also works fine, as long as I'm not trying to resize it. Once I do try to resize, I get the "...[image path] is not recognized by the 'identify' command" error. There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996102/rails-paperclip-and-passenger-is-not-recognized-by-the-identify-command) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420790/completely-stumped-by-is-not-recognized-by-the-identify-command-error-in-rail) about this, here are the things I've done from reading those:

ImageMagick is installed in a directory w/out spaces - C:\ImageMagick-6.5.6-Q8

ImageMagick is on my PATH - I can do `identify -version` and get the version info.

I've added the following to my `config/environments/development.rb` :

`Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "C:/ImageM~1"`

I also tried that with the full path, until [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981336/ruby-on-rails-paperclip-identify-command-working-in-cmd-but-not-in-app) suggested the `~` abbreviation.

Suggestions?